# Need help to convert from curl to request

Tags: node.js, http, curl, express, request

I have a curl like this
`curl -u 209f734234234j556l45l6j64218ecffb0a900aff998c8e0: -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Ionic-Application-Id: 123k4j54k" https://push.ionic.io/api/v1/push -d '{"tokens": ["token1,token2,token3"],"notification":{"alert":"NarayaN","android":{"payload":{"$state":"app.home"}}}}'`

Which i have converted it to this state

```
var request = require('request');

var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-Ionic-Application-Id': 'e4ea3c2d'
};

var options = {
    url: 'https://push.ionic.io/api/v1/push',
    headers: headers
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
    }
}

request(options, callback);
```

I am having trouble with -u param. How to use that in http req

By looking at the req i can see that the `method is post`

Any Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.auth()` method

```
request.get('http://some.server.com/').auth('username', 'password', false);
// or
request.get('http://some.server.com/', {
  'auth': {
    'user': 'username',
    'pass': 'password',
    'sendImmediately': false
  }
});
// or
request.get('http://some.server.com/').auth(null, null, true, 'bearerToken');
// or
request.get('http://some.server.com/', {
  'auth': {
    'bearer': 'bearerToken'
  }
});
```

https://github.com/request/request#http-authentication

Or

https://github.com/request/request#oauth-signing